# Error: Invalid hook call when using with redux

Tags: django, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

Sorry if I am asking a beginner's level question. I am new to React.js and recently I have been trying to grasps the concepts by following this tutorial:
[JustDjango](https://github.com/justdjango/DjReact)

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a login form which uses redux to store the states, my code is as follows :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button, Spin } from 'antd/lib';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const antIcon = <Icon type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;


class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        this.props.onAuth(values.userName, values.password);
        this.props.history.push('/');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    let errorMessage = null;
    if (this.props.error) {
        errorMessage = (
            <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
        );
    }

    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
        <div>
            {errorMessage}
            {
                this.props.loading ?

                <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

                :

                <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form">

                    <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('userName', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
                    })(
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    {getFieldDecorator('password', {
                        rules: [{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }],
                    })(
                        <Input prefix={<Icon type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    )}
                    </FormItem>

                    <FormItem>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                        Login
                    </Button>
                    Or 
                    <NavLink 
                        style={{marginRight: '10px'}} 
                        to='/signup/'> signup
                    </NavLink>
                    </FormItem>
                </Form>
            }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.useForm()(NormalLoginForm);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onAuth: (username, password) => dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password)) 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WrappedNormalLoginForm);
```

The error traceback shows that the error is coming from :

```
 76 | const WrappedNormalLoginForm = Form.useForm()(NormalLoginForm);
  77 | 
  78 | const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  79 |     return {
```

Some google search on this particular error shows that this error has something to do with hooks being defined in a classed based component , however i do not understand why :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {......
```

is considered a hook

Will greatly appreciate anybody's help!

Comment: Can build a sandbox for this, so that  its easier debug the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React hooks only used by functional components. You used class components.

Shortly, `Form.useForm()` the method is only used functional components, you can read it from this link below:

https://ant.design/components/form/

Comment: thanks for the help. I did not realize that useForm is a hook , i have since changed the form to be function based